# IDE Eclipse does not link to other opened project but to its jar

Tags: eclipse, maven, jar, dependencies

I have a workspace with two opened projects : project A and project B project A, into its pom.xml, has dependency to project B. project A, in its Maven dependencies, should link to 'opened' project B but it doesn't. It links to project B 'jar'.

I add some explanations.. In a project with two projects A and B, A linking to B, I should see in project A 'Maven Dependencies' something like that :

```
-hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar
-hikariCP-3.2.0.jar
 other jars.. 
-my-projectB[without test code]
```

but i see :

```
-hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar
-hikariCP-3.2.0.jar
 other jars..
-my-projectB.jar
```

Could you help me solving this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The *workspace resolution*  can be activated or deactivated on the projects. You need to check whether it's active.

Comment: thanks. more details had been welcomed. usually responders are more exhaustive.

Comment: Right click on a project, "Maven -> Enable Workspace Resolution".

Comment: absolutly perfect!

Answer (score 0):

i resolved my issue by doing this :

going to the file org.eclipse.m2e.core.prefs
into .settings folder

checking the file contains this item :

```
   resolveWorkspaceProjects=true
```